# Is "ringing somebody up" exclusive to telephone use in British English?

Tags: british-english

Is ringing somebody up exclusive to telephone use, or can it be used to say you made a call on somebody's person?

**EDIT**: Note that my question is specifically asking about *British English*; I would love to hear from *an actual Brit* the answer.

Comment: In American English, at least, *to ring someone up* can only mean to give them a telephone call. I'd be surprised if British English were any different.

Comment: @Billare: you mean call on somebody *in person* ? call on somebody's person sounds a bit weird.

Comment: and *give him a ring* means the same - unless you're proposing :)

Comment: "Knocking someone up" has ***very*** different meanings in British vs. American English.

Comment: It _is_ used in AmE, but it's very much more rare than in BrE.  There are Americans who will not understand the expression at all, so it doesn't have critical mass there.  OTOH it's not just understood but widely used in the UK (well, at least it was when I was there last).

Comment: No one brought up _knocking [somebody] up_....please save the jokes for relevant questions.

Comment: @Billare: So, what do you require? Proof of residency? scan of the passeport? What happens if a Brit answers who is currently living oversea?

Comment: @F'x I don't "require" anything.  I said _I would love_ to hear from a Brit. How would they establish their "Britishness"? By demonstrating that they are familiar with the contexts in which certain colloquialisms are used in British English, whether or not they're living smack dab in the middle of East End or make their home in Timbuktu.  Duh.

Comment: @Billare: the active top UK users are @Bruno, @Colin, @Noldorin, @Brian, @Rhodri. But beware, as I said: it's hard to prove a negative.

Comment: As a side note: to 'give you a bell', or a 'tinkle' can be common in Britain, slanging this out a bit.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: hey, you are British, aren't you? Could you confirm or infirm my answer below?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: what about "give me a *buzz*" - is that Brit too?

Comment: @F'x: I most certainly am that, and yes - I delayed this reply to give time to think of even a single instance where 'ringing someone up' might be used in meaning something else, I can't. If I were to post an answer then it would only serve to reiterate your point plus add my (in)experience as noted here.

Comment: @JoseK: 'Give me a buzz' is not unheard of either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *[Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0711910?rskey=FPHLWz&result=2#m_en_gb0711910)* clearly states:

> **ring:** [trans., Brit.] call by telephone

The [*Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ring_4) also says “to make a telephone call to someone”.

Though it's always hard to prove a negative, I've never seen it used for something other than a telephone call, and looking through some recent [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ring%20him%20up%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2011&lr=lang_en) excerpts doesn't bring any other use either.

---

<sup>Answer Officially Sponsored by Mr. Disappointment, Britishness Expert!</sup>

Answer (score 7):

It may be localized, but 'ringing someone up' is used in the American mid-atlantic area to refer to the process of tallying someone's purchases at a store, eg:

> I can ring someone up in this line.  (said by a cashier who is unoccupied)

or

> She's ringing someone up right now, but will be with you in a minute.  (when you ask to see the manager, and she's occupied.)

Comment: I can confirm similar usage in Southern US English.

Comment: and in the Great Lakes area as well.

Comment: I can confirm this usage in Pittsburgh (I lived there 5 years)… but also that it *doesn’t* occur in the UK, in my experience (I’m a Brit).  In the UK, the cashier (=*clerk*, for some US speakers) may ring up your purchases at the till, but if she rings *you* up, that’s a phone call.

Comment: Also California usage. Worth pointing out this tends to be anachronistic with modern cash registers, that don't ring.

Answer (score 1):

It just means to make a telephone call. It is never used in relation to till operations, in the form "ring  up". You might ring up some items, though.

Answer (score -1):

There is "ring the curtain up", which means to signify the end of something.

There is also "ring something up" on a cash register; it can also mean "to register sales".